# How to allow dot,underscore in URL asp.net /aspx?

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I was searching "LME7_1." text in textbox, my url is look like below 
http://localhost:49312/buscar/LME7_1.

It will give me error like **The resource cannot be found.**
any one know how to resolve it.

Comment: Are you asking about configuring the routing?

Comment: @TsahiAsher something like !, have you any idea ?

Comment: Is that URL *correct*?  The question does not contain enough information for us to offer an answer.

Comment: Can you show us your routing configuration? And just to make things clear, we are talking about WebForms here right?

Comment: @TsahiAsher , yes exactly ,this is code :      
                                
   System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("", "buscar/{StrBuscador}/", "~/Store.aspx");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must have an array that contains special characters like `.`,`/`,`\`,`{space}`,etc, and replace them to something else then send it to url, and after that, when you want to work with the url, just replace them to before values. i do it before and worked.

Comment: That's working around the problem instead of solving it. What if the user uses your replacement characters? How would you know it's user input and not your replacement?